# Spring Properties showing as Null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a Spring Boot application, generated by JHipster.

Am trying to add some new properties to the application-dev.yml file but my class is seeing the values null, even after spending some hours with Google.

Added the following to the top of `application-dev.yml`:

```
host: 1.2.3.4
port: 5555
```

In my class I have

```
@Component
public class ExampleUtils {

    @Value("${host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${port}")
    private String port;
}
```

The class is in a new directory under the source root.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your application-dev.yml.. maybe there is something wrong with the format.

Comment: I tested @Value for properties JHipster set properties, and they are coming through as Null as well. Since these properties are correctly reflected when gthe app runs I cant see the problem is the formate of the .yml.

Answer (score 2):

in your application.properties set

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

or when you run the application parse the command line args follows

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: I am confident dev profile is being used as it is showing as such in the logs. Also, when I change a value in applicaton-dev it flows through.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to add the new properties you add to a @ConfigurationProperties class.
At least this way I never had problems adding properties.
Have a look at the docs : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties